# optimal loop by rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to iterate table by rows, calculating some values and returning it to resulting dataframe.

On big data, the process is very long.

My question is, if choosing resources and changing working time funds inside the loop would be not from the dataframe, but from a list of lists or list of dictionaries, will the process be faster?

Simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
import heapq
case_list=[]
Operations = pd.DataFrame({'operation_id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Work': [4, 5, 6, 4]})
Machines = pd.DataFrame({'operation_id': [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4], 'MachineID': [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], 'MinusTimeFundMachine': [-4, -5, -6, 0, -5,-6]})
Workers = pd.DataFrame({'operation_id': [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4], 'MachineID': [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], 'worker': [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], 'MinusTimeFundSotr': [-4, -5, -6, -4, -5,-6]})
print(Operations)
print(Machines)
print(Workers)
for ix in Operations.index:

    #Choosing resources
    dct = Machines[Machines['operation_id'] == Operations.loc[ix]['operation_id']][
        ["MinusTimeFundMachine", "MachineID"]].values.tolist()
    heapq.heapify(dct)
    MinusTimeFundMachine, MachineID = heapq.heappop(dct)

    dct2 = Workers[(Workers['operation_id'] == Operations.loc[ix]['operation_id']) & (Workers.MachineID == MachineID)][
        ["MinusTimeFundSotr", "worker"]].values.tolist()
    heapq.heapify(dct2)
    MinusTimeFundSotr2, worker = heapq.heappop(dct2)


    #Changing working time funds
    Workers.loc[Workers.worker == worker, 'MinusTimeFundSotr'] = Workers.loc[
                                                                    Workers.worker == worker, 'MinusTimeFundSotr'] + Operations.loc[ix]['Work']
    Machines.loc[Machines.MachineID == MachineID, 'MinusTimeFundMachine'] = Machines.loc[
                                                                        Machines.MachineID == MachineID, 'MinusTimeFundMachine'] + Operations.loc[ix]['Work']



    case_list.append({'Operation': Operations.loc[ix]['operation_id'], 'MachineID': MachineID, 'worker': worker})

print()
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(case_list))
```

Comment: Question is how much data is much? And another thing - it will be not more convinient to use numpy for calculations? WHat I mean by that, filter data you want to filter, put it in to numpy arrrays and then perform calculations, then merge those to filtered dataframe

Comment: dataframe "Opearations" for ex 500k rows, and <5 megabytes, 3-5 resources for each operation, in Machines and Workers. Will try np array if it is more productive)

Comment: What is the operation you want to perform? What is the expected output?

Comment: Operation is just the name of df, in example loop returns 3 values which are appending to resulting dataframe or dictionary

Comment: Personally I think <5 Mb is low end of "much data" :D You will not gain significant time reduction even using numpy arrays. I guess you don't need this calculation in real time, so gaining few seconds is not that beneficial. In my dayjob I deal with ~ 12 GB per data source, so then it has real impact in execution time. Tho you can check for your own convinience working with np arrays and matrixes, for sure it will help in time reduction. In general pandas is not extremely quick in this type of operations. Second thing you can check is Polars lib , which is much faster then pandas